# Are the values of generators of a homomorphism of groups distinct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the fact that a homomorphism $ f:G \rightarrow F $  is determined by ist values at a set of generators $E$ of $G$, $G=EE^{-1}$, it means that $f(x_{i})=b_{i}, x_{i}\in E$ and $b_{i} \in F$.

1. Since a homomorphism must not be an isomorphism, does this means that the $b_{i}$ must not all be distinct ? Say that $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$, for $x_{1} \neq x_{2} $, two generators of $G$. It follows that $x_{1}, x_{2} \in ker f$. I am not quite sure what consequences this induces in the group $F$.
2. In the case of the homomorphism $Z\rightarrow G$, it is characterised by ist value on the generator $1$ of $Z$. How many endomorphisms and isomorphisms $f: Z\rightarrow Z$ are there ? If i set $f(1)=1 $ it is clear that $f$ will be an isomorphism since $f(n)=nf(1).$

Can somebody help me out to answer these questions. Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

1) A group homomorphism can be an isomorphism.  In fact an isomorphism is *by definition* a homomorphism that also happens to be a bijection.  There are homomorphisms that are not isomorphisms, but all isomorphisms are homomorphisms.  Isomorphisms are a special kind of homomorphism.

So no, it is not required that two basis elements get sent to the same place.  Also, by the way, if you have a homomorphism that is not an isomorphism it is still not required that that happens.  For example $\mathbb Z^2$ is generated by $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.  The map $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $(a, b) \mapsto 3a - 2b$ sends the generators to $3$ and $-2$ and these are distinct but the map is still not an isomorphism.  For example $(2, 3)$ is in the kernel.

2) There are countably many endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$, one for each element of $\mathbb Z$.  The group $\mathbb Z$ is *free* of rank $1$ (we can take the number $1$ to be the generator).  This means that to specify a homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to G$ you just have to specify an element $g \in G$ to be the image of $1$ and any choice of $g$ gives you a well defined homomorphism.  So there are $|G|$ many homomorphisms $\mathbb Z \to G$.  A homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ will only be an isomorphism if $1$ is sent to a generator of $\mathbb Z$.  There are only two generators of $\mathbb Z$, they are $1$ and $-1$ so there are only two isomorphisms $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$.  The identity $n \mapsto n$ and negation $n \mapsto -n$.

Comment: Thanks. For the point 1, my question was if the values on the generators are all distinct and not the contrary, if they were the same.

Comment: They can be all distinct or not, both are possible.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an isomorphism and a homomorphism (which is not an isomorphism) where they are not all distinct, i.e. for $x_{i} \neq x_{j}, f(x_{i})= f(x_{j}).$ Thanks again. Your example of the homomorphism above made me understand a lot.

Comment: An isomorphism must be an injective map, and an injective map sends distinct elements to distinct elements, so if the map is an isomorphism then the generators must go to distinct elements.

Comment: For a homomorphism where the generators don't go to distinct elements take $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $(a, b) \mapsto a + b$.